# Mypy ignores value type of the dict

Tags: python, mypy

This should not typecheck and it does fail if `123` is used instead of `body` (see XXX line) , but how to tell mypy about it?

I'm expecting this to fail saying that `str` is not one of `Tag` or `bs4.element.NavigableString`

```py
from typing import Generator, TypedDict, Optional
import srsly
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

# from notebooks/prodify.ipynb


def html_to_text(html: str) -> str:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

    # kill all script and style elements
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out

    # get text
    text = soup.get_text()
    return text


def body_only(html: str) -> Tag | bs4.element.NavigableString | None:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    # kill all script and style elements
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()    # rip it out
    body = soup.find('body')
    return body


# https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict
class Example(TypedDict):
    html: str
    text: str


def g(data: Example) -> Optional[Example]:
    print(data['html'])
    body = body_only(data['html'])
    # print(body)
    if body is not None:
        # print(body)
        # Keep only body because page HTML breaks prodigy CSS
        example: Example = {"html": body,  # XXX 123 does not typecheck though
                            "text": html_to_text(body.get_text())}
        # print(example)
        return example
    return None
```

this is my `mypy.ini` for the refercence

```ini
[mypy]
python_version = 3.10
warn_unused_configs = True
disallow_incomplete_defs = True
disallow_untyped_defs = True
```

and im on Python 3.10.11

Comment: If nothing else, you should probably write some function with type `Callable[[Tag|NavigableString], str]` to convert `body` to a string in order to build the `dict`. Are you saying that right now, `mypy` allows a `Tag|NavigableString` where a `str` is expected?

Comment: yes, @chepner as of now mypy allows Tag|NavigableString where a str is expected

Comment: [`NavigableString`](https://git.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/tree/bs4/element.py#n933) inherits from `str`. `Tag` does not, so this behaviour is still not obvious.

Comment: Hm, wait. I just installed a fresh venv (`mypy==1.3.0, beautifulsoup4==4.12.2, types-beautifulsoup4==4.12.0.5`) and got the expected error: `Cannot find implementation or library stub for module named "srsly"` and `Incompatible types (expression has type "Union[Tag, NavigableString]", TypedDict item "html" has type "str")`. Are you sure you have bs4 stubs installed? Please share more repro details.

Comment: Yes, @SUTerliakov exactly what I thought that actually the issue is that NavigatableString inherits from str and because of that that usage could be valid (but then it should manifest that it does not cover all variants like Tag and None but if mypy is that advanced in typechecking is beyond my knowledge of its internals)

Comment: Again, your issue does not reproduce, I don't see any `mypy` bug here, it works as expected and generates the desired error. Please make sure that you have stubs installed. `mypy` certainly doesn't fail to detect when one of the union members does not satisfy some constraints. Please add `reveal_type(Tag)` and `reveal_type(NavigableString)` to your code and post `mypy` output.

Comment: What @SUTerliakov said. Also, please read the article on [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).